# preg_replace for a specific domain name

Tags: replace, preg-replace

I was using str_replace to rewrite URLs to PDFs from https://example.com/documents/en/whatever.PDF to https://example.com/documents/es/whatever_SPANISH.pdf

This is what I was using

```
    if($_COOKIE['googtrans'] == "/en/es") { //Check the google translate cookie
            $text = str_replace('/documents/en/', '/documents/es/', $text);
            $text = str_replace('.pdf', '_SPANISH.pdf', $text);
    }
```

The problem is, if the page contains a PDF linked to another page (not my own website), example https://othersite.example.com/whatever.pdf, it becomes https://othersite.example.com/whatever_SPANISH.pdf which isn't valid on other people's sites.  I want to ignore offsite links and only change URLs on my site.

So what I would like to do is look for the string:
https://example.com/documents/en/whateverfilename.pdf and pull that file name out and change it to https://example.com/documents/es/whateverfilename_SPANISH.pdf
(Switching the en to es and also appending the _SPANISH to the end of the PDF filename.

How can I do this. Have tried various preg_replace but can't get my syntax right.

```
    if($_COOKIE['googtrans'] == "/en/es") {
            $text = str_replace('/documents/en/', '/documents/es/', $text);
            $text = str_replace('.pdf', '_SPANISH.pdf', $text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the replacement in 1 go using a regex and 2 capture group values in the replacement.

```
\b(https?://\S*?/documents/)en(/\S*)\.pdf\b
```

Or match the domain name:

```
\b(https?://example\.com/documents/)en(/\S*)\.pdf\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(https?://\S*?/documents/)` Capture **group 1**, match the protocol and then optional non whitespace characters until the first occurrence of `/documents/`
- `en` Match literally
- `(/\S*)` Capture **group 2**, match `/` followed by optional non whitspace chars
- `\.pdf\b` Match `.pdf` followed by a word boundary

In the replacement use the 2 capture groups denoted by `$1` and `$2`:

```
$1es$2_SPANISH.pdf
```

See the [regex group captures](https://regex101.com/r/IOZ6ZY/1).

Example:

```
$regex = '~\b(https?://\S*?/documents/)en(/\S*)\.pdf\b~';
$text = "https://example.com/documents/en/whateverfilename.pdf";

$result = preg_replace($regex, "$1es$2_SPANISH.pdf", $text);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
https://example.com/documents/es/whateverfilename_SPANISH.pdf
```

---

If you want to match the same amount of forward slashes as in your example, you can make use of a negated character class `[^\s/]` to exclude matching whitespace characters or forward slashes:

```
\b(https?://[^\s/]+/documents/)en/([^\s/]+)\.pdf\b
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eYhL4z/1).